# Advantage of C++ functor use for comparison

Tags: c++, function, stdvector, functor

I have seen many articles here but still haven't figured out the advantage of a functor class over a simple function in the case of comparison. So I have a code excerpt in which they want to sort a vector of `unsigned char *` by simply going through each character and comparing the ASCII code with priority from left to right.

The functor is

```
class Sorter {
private:
    unsigned int length;
public:
    Sorter( unsigned int _length ): length( _length ) {}
    bool operator()( const unsigned char* keyl, const unsigned char* keyr ) { return cmpKey( keyl, keyr, length ); }
};
```

and the `cmpKey()` function basically does what I described above. The call to sort the data is

```
sort( localList.begin(), localList.end(), Sorter( 100 ) );
```

where 100 is the length of each string. So, I have read that the functor has the advantage of storing the stage from call to call and allows the class to be used as an ordinary function. I have two questions:

1. What is the advantage of this in this case?
2. How many instances of `Sorter` class will be created? Is it only 1 or as many as the elements of `locaList`?

Comment: What is `cmpKey()` and why to you need the `length`?

Comment: How would you pass `100` as 3rd parameter to `cmpKey` without the functor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary use of functors is to create functions at runtime that possess some state. This is important in scenarios where you need a function to possess some information, but you cannot pass this information into the function as a parameter. One common example of this is in algorithms like `std::sort` where the comparator function **must** take only two arguments (the things to compare) so you cannot just pass in extra information as parameters. You must instead create a function object at runtime and pass in that information in the constructor.

This is essentially what you do when you call

```
 sort( localList.begin(), localList.end(), Sorter( 100 ) );
```

You are creating a Sorter function wherein you pass the information about the 100 when constructing the function. Calling it still requires only two parameters so this will work in the `std::sort` algorithm. There is no way to do this with regular functions, besides things like `std::bind`.

Comment: `std::bind` isn't deprecated, and constructs a functor of unspecified (i.e. implementation defined) type

Answer (score 5):

1. The advantage is that you can store state.  In your case the state is `length=100`.
2. A single functor is created when you call `Sorter(100)`.  It may be copied a small number of times (e.g. to call `sort()`), but not for every element.

Comment: As far as I understand the cost of passing the `length` argument to a simple function each time would be larger than using functor. I also assume that if there is no common state across the calls then there is no other advantage that could make functors preferable. Is this correct?

Comment: @mgus A function that took length as an argument **isn't allowed** as the third argument of sort. It's not a matter of cost, it's a matter of being the right type.

Comment: @mgus: Another reason to prefer functors is that you can use partial template specialization with them, whereas it is not allowed with plain functions.  And as Caleth said, you *cannot* pass `length` to a plain function.  Try it and see.